# How do you delete a Facebook group now?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am the sole admin of a private Facebook group. I would like to delete it but can't find out how. If I click on the 3 dots there's the option to archive or leave, but not delete. I would like all the content, including posts, to be deleted. If this is possible, how is it done?

I tried Google searching but haven't found a good answer. For example [this](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-delete-a-facebook-group) makes it sound like once you've manually removed all members then there will be the option to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/174988392554409) page:

> If you're an admin of a group, you can delete or archive it. Groups are deleted when they have no members. Deleting a group is a permanent action that cannot be reversed.

> **To delete a group:**
>
> 1. From your News Feed, click **Groups** in the left menu and select your group from **Groups You Manage** or by searching for it.
> 2. Click **Members** below the name of the group.
> 3. Click on **...** next to each member's name and select **Remove member**.
> 4. Click **Confirm**.
> 5. Once you’ve removed the other members, click  next to your name and select **Leave group**.
> 6. Click **Leave Group**.

> Note: If you're an admin, you can't delete a group you didn't create unless the original creator chooses to leave it. Group members aren't notified when you delete a group.

Comment: So if a group has hundreds of members each must be deleted manually? I find that hard to believe...

Comment: Not user friendly but this is how it works as of now.